# How do you install pod lights in a finished basement ceiling where the drywall was installed with no furring strips?

Tags: electrical

I used to have two track lights which I am trying to replace (they are removed)
I am left with two electrical boxes (1 and 2 in the picture) one is connected to the other, they were installed before the ceiling was finished.

They are not symetricaly installed and not in a position where I could reuse them.

After removing one of the boxes I can see that the ceiling is built without furring strips , there is insulation and there seem to be some reinforcing 2x6 or larger installd as in the picture below

What is the best way to run cables to the positions where these lights will be installed ? Flex drill bit ?

[image]

Edit:
I just realized there is airducts there :-(( I need to cut a narrow channel in the drywall which I will have to fill in with mud later
This will allow me to route/drill the cable on the east west direction for each North-South line of lights
[image]

Comment: You've been here long enough, you should know not to put your answer back into the question, but to write it up as an answer down below, then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that by "pot lights" you refer to recessed can lights ?

Either remove the ceiling drywall and wire things properly. This is going to be the easiest and cleanest install for you.

Or

Try and remove select small pieces of drywall so that you can drill wires through what I see as blocks in your drawing (the white wood pieces). You will still need to get wiring through your floor joists (the red/ brown wood members in your drawing). This all might be possible but would require an amount of skill and creativity with "fishing" wires- and also adds the possibility of damaging other existing wiring and/ or piping that is hidden in the ceiling.

With that light layout you have shown, I would remove the drywall ceiling- or at least most of it- and replace it after wiring is complete. There is going to be a lot of drywall/ taping/ finishing and painting either way.

Comment: fixed the "pot" lights error :-))
At most I would remove a narrow strip that I can fill with mud later.  that strip will go alon g the line between 1 and 2. My bet is that there are very slim chances that the white pieces are there. I might have cable runs that go across the ceiling to feed power outlets on the north wall in the picture. The rest of the basement is south of the picture. I just realized that I also have 4 air ducts between 1 and 2 ....

Comment: I agree with minime a couple of channels in the Sheetrock is the way pros do it. Then 1 new sheet cut into strips to fill the Chanel’s, mud tape and texture is much less work this way and cost less.